# Bitmaps leaking on Android app

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-fragments

`Bitmaps` are, for some reason, leaking in my application. I am using a lazy list with disk and memory caching, this later limited to around 10 Mb. The longer I test the app the more `Bitmaps` keep stored on memory and never released. This app makes heavy use of `ListViews` with `Adapters` as well a full screen background `ImageViews` downloaded from a server.

I have been investigating for 3 days already with `DDMS` and `MAT`, but I can not locate who creates the leaked `Bitmaps` or what is the reference that prevents them from being garbage collected. Many `Bitmaps` are being referenced by the lazy list memory cache, but others they just don't have a reference that could be easily associated with one of the app classes. They are just referenced by different `Views` like `ImageViews` or `Layouts`.

I suspect this can be due to this app less-than-optimal design of using a **single `Activity` and one `Fragment` for each screen** in the app. However, there are no references to my `Fragment` classes.

Any idea of what can be holding those `Bitmaps`? Is it possible that the `Fragments` are released but the listeners such as `OnClickListener` are preventing the Views from being released because they all use the `Context` from the single `Activity`?